# Drag and Drop automatico após captura de imagem

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estou fazendo um formulário de cadastro no qual os usuários podem se cadastrar arrastando e soltando ou tirar uma foto com sua webcam, porém ao tirar uma foto via webcam (já implementado esse recurso), a ideia seria realizar o "drag and drop" dessa mesma imagem tirada para o componente de "drag and drop", é possível usar o javascript para tal funcionalidade? Ou alguma ferramenta semelhante?

Comment: Sim, é possível fazer drag and drop com javascript, mas não sei exatamente como faz. Este site faz uso do drag and drop para peças de xadrez: http://www.expertchessstrategies.com/javascript-computer-chess.shtml

Comment: A ideia seria realizar o drag and drop automaticamente sem nenhuma interação do cliente que no caso a unica interação seria tirar a foto da webcam, o restante seria feito a partir de um javascript